# How to send lifecycle_rules to a s3 module in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have a terraform module that creates a s3 bucket. I want the module to be able to accept lifecycle rules.

```
 resource "aws_s3_bucket" "somebucket"  {
  bucket = "my-versioning-bucket"
  acl    = "private"



 lifecycle_rule {
   prefix  = "config/"
   enabled = true

   noncurrent_version_transition {
     days          = 30
     storage_class = "STANDARD_IA"
   }
 }
}
```

I want to be able to to send above lifecycle_rule block of code when I call the module. I tried to send it through a variable but it did not work. I have done some research but no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.